# How do I use a Python virtual environment to manage dependencies for my project?

Tags: python, linux, macos, dependencies, virtualenv

How do I use a Python virtual environment to manage dependencies for my project?

How I  manage dependencies by python for my project?

By using a virtual environment, you create an isolated environment for your project, preventing conflicts with other projects. The requirements.txt file can then be shared with others to recreate the same environment.

Answer (score 3):

I usually do this in the console. You need to find something like:

`venv/bin/activate` or
`venv/lib/bin/activate`

and then run:

`source venv/bin/activate`

The result should look like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvNvc.png)

Running dependency install should now automatically be installed in the virtual environment.